# Is a digital signature really needed?

Tags: tls, public-key-infrastructure

I'm trying to understand the goal of a digital signature in PKI/TLS. I understand that digital signature provide us Data integrity, Authentication and Non-repudiation.

But, why is it necessary to use digital signatures in secure communication, considering that someone with access to the private key can change the digital signature and potentially compromise the security of the system?

Thank your for your help!

Comment: *"someone with access to the private key"* - the attacker having the private key is not part of the thread model of a PKI. That's why it is called a **private** key.

Comment: What I meant is cryptography give us already the Data integrity, Authentication and Non-repudiation principles. If you're able to decrypt the message we know from who it's coming, if the message has been changed during the transit it meant that the private key has leaked. 
As we need the private key to compute the digital signature, I don't get the digital signature added value

Comment: @ragnar suppose you connect to paypal.com.  The server that you connect to sends you a cert that appears to be valid for paypal.com.  But, how do you know that you are in fact connected to the true server for paypal.com, and not the server of an attacker that has copied paypal's cert - unless the server is able to prove that it is in possession of the private key that corresponds with the public key in the cert?  The true server for paypal.com can prove this, by using the private key to sign something, whereas the attacker is not able to do this, because he does not have the private key.

Comment: *" If you're able to decrypt the message we know from who it's coming,"* - This is wrong. Please explain how you came to this conclusion so that we can point were you went wrong.

Comment: @mti2935 thanks for your reply. I do understand how PKI and asymmetric cryptography work. My question is related to the specific field digital signature available on x.509 certificate. The digital signature (via hash function) gives us Data integrity, Authentication and Non-repudiation.  Isn't already the case thanks to asymmetric cryptography?!
What I meant, if the private leaked the digital signature can be changed during a man in the middle attack.

Comment: _"If you're able to decrypt the message we know from who it's coming"_ - we only know its coming from someone who has your public key, which could be anybody (it's a public key after all).

Comment: @ragnar: "What I meant, if the private leaked the digital signature can be changed during a man in the middle attack."* - exactly. The security of the signature depends on keeping the private key private. Hence the name private key. But this does not mean that signature is not needed - it only means that the private key needs to be protected.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, as we use the public key for decrypting the messages. We can assume that the messages come from the private key owner.

Comment: @ragnar: *"as we use the public key for decrypting the messages"* - no we don't. Not in TLS or PKI. We use the public key to verify signatures only. Using the public key for decryption would be foolish, since the public key is considered public (it's in the name) and thus anybody could decrypt the traffic.

Comment: We all agree that the private key must be private. But this private key can leak. What's the added of the digital signature?  As it can be changed by a man in the middle.

Comment: *"But this private key can leak. "* - and the world might be destroyed by an alien space ship. Yes, it is possible but it is not part of the threat scenario.  The private key is considered private -  hence the name. There are other mechanisms to deal with the risk of private key compromise, like revoking certificates, limited life time...

Comment: You have to assume that the private key hasn't been leaked unless informed otherwise.  If it is leaked, the owner should inform the CA which issued the certificate, who should then revoke that certificate.  All relying parties should check for revocation before using a certificate for verifying a digital signature.  If you're using self-signed certificates (or asymmetric keys without certifying them) then you should inform all relying parties that the key has been compromised, so that they stop trusting the public key to verify signatures.

Answer (score 3):

Only one party ever has a given private key - that's what is meant by private - so the standard assumption is that only the holder of the private key can generate a signature such that the corresponding public key can successfully verify it. This is the crux of digital signatures in general.

In TLS, there are two places the digital signatures are used:

---

First, every certificate contains a signature created with the private key of the certificate authority (CA) that issued the certificate. This is used as a way to, essentially, put the reputation of the CA behind the claims in the certificate (claims being things like "this certificate is for site A, the site's public key is B, the certificate can be used to authenticate the site and securely exchange keys, and the certificate is valid from date C to D"). Anybody can make a certificate *signing request* (CSR) that contains those claims, but until a trusted CA signs them to produce an actual certificate, there's no reason to trust them. Since the CA is staking their reputation (and entire ability to do business) on the correctness of those claims, if the certificate's signature is valid, that's pretty strong evidence that the key does belong to who it says.

Of course, you need to know the CA's public key in order to verify the signature. Fortunately, your browser either already knows this (the certificates - including public keys - of the "root" CAs are built into browsers and other TLS clients), or (if there's an "intermediate" CA) the server will send the intermediate CA('s) certificate(s) and the browser will verify each certificate using the public key of the CA that supposedly issued it, until it gets one that is issued by a trusted root CA. If it does (and the certificates are all valid), then the browser trusts that the certificate for site A is in fact legitimate. If the browser is unable to validate any step in the chain of certificates, or the chain terminates without reaching a trusted root CA, then the certificate is considered untrustworthy and the browser won't complete the connection.

In this case, there's no worry about the holder(s) of the private key(s) - the CA(s) - issuing a modified certificate (that is, re-signing a modified certificate to fix the signature, which would have been invalidated by the modification) or issuing a cert from an untrustworthy / incorrect CSR. CAs that do anything like that go out of business extremely quickly, because nobody trusts them anymore, and a company that isn't trusted can't meaningfully be a CA since the whole point is that CAs are assumed trustworthy. Therefore their reputation is literally essential to their continued existence as a company, and they guard it - and therefore are careful of what they sign - accordingly.

---

Second, there's the short-lived signatures used during the TLS handshake. The exact details vary depending on the exact protocol version and the selected cipher suite, but broadly, the client (e.g. browser) will always want to prove that the server controls the private key corresponding to the public key in the server's certificate. One of the simplest ways to do so is to sign some random and unpredictable data. For example, during a Diffie-Hellman key exchange of any sort (typically these days an elliptic-curve DH using ephemeral parameters), the the server's public parameters need to be signed so that the client knows that an attacker hasn't replaced the parameters. Historically only that key exchange portion was signed by the server, but these days the server signs the entire "transcript", including both [EC]DH parameters and random "nonces" that are generated by each side. that it sends to the client. The client can and will verify the signature on the public paramters before combining them with its own private parameters to generate the key.

With ephemeral [EC]DH key exchages server's public and private parameters are only ever used once and forgotten immediately afterward, but even if an attacker intercepts the (signed) public parameter and replays it into a different handshake, that won't do the attacker any good; without knowing either side's private parameter, the attacker wouldn't be able to derive the same key that the server and client derive. The private parameters never even touch the network, so there's no opportunity for an attacker to tamper with them. TLS 1.3's step of having the server sign the whole transcript means that even if an attacker gains the server's [EC]DH private parameter, the attacker can't replay a captured signature because the transcript includes random client-chosen data as well.

In some cases (mutual TLS), the client will also have a public/private key pair, with the public key in the client's own "client certificate" (exactly the same as a server certificate, except it identifies a user or other client, rather than a site/server). In mutual TLS cases, the client proves possession of the private key to the server by signing the transcript as well; since this will be unique in all cases (due to nonces and hopefully-unique key exchange params) and is not fully under the control of either side, successfully verifying such a signature is strong evidence that the client does in fact have the private key.

---

Hope that helps! There are other uses for digital signatures - signing an email, signing a driver, timestamping arbitrary data, growing a blockchain, etc. - but those are the TLS-specific ones. Note that once the handshake is done, there's no more digital signatures - or asymmetric cryptography in general - throughout the rest of the process.

Comment: Sadly browsers and OS vendors will put just about any *government*-affiliated CA in the root trust list, and there are no market forces punishing them for misbehavior.  (This is not meant as an anti-government rant, but there are good practical reasons: Organizations in your own country's government often have good intentions but poor security hygiene, and foreign governments definitely don't have your best interests at heart)

Comment: If you're worried about CAs issuing certificates without permission, there are solutions for that. The main one today is the Certificate Transparency system, where browsers will require that all TLS certificates be publicly listed on several log services through the Certificate Transparency system. That way, if a certificate is issued without permission, anyone can see it.

Comment: Nit: in TLSv1.3 the server signature covers the transcript (like optional client signature does in all versions) not just ServerKX body -- and 1.3 also moves the DHE exchange up to the ClientHello and ServerHello, so both sides of it, as well as both nonces, are included in the transcript.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Whoops, thanks for the reminder, I totally knew that once upon a time, I swear! Cuts down a round trip too.

Answer (score 0):

So, you are right in sense that if the private key is leaked then the message in transit can be decrypted, however, this is possible in case of certain algorithms only, for example like **RSA**.

In case of Algos like **Diffie Helman**, the decryption won't be possible even if the private key is leaked. This is due to a property called `forward secrecy` or `PFS(perfect forward secrecy)`.
You can google more about this, in case you want to go in deep.

Comment: you are probably talking about the symmetric keys  (phase 2)once the auth is done with asymmetric keys (private and pub keys). The OP is talking about the first phase